# Build pipeline from Oracle DB to AWS DynamoDB

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, etl

I have an Oracle instance running on a stand alone EC2 VM, I want to do two things.

1) Copy the data from one of my Oracle tables into a cloud directory that can be read by DynamoDB. This will only be done once.

2) Then daily I want to append any changes to that source table into the DynamoDB table as another row that will share an id so I can visualize how that row is changing over time.

Ideally I'd like a solution that would be as easy as pipeing the results of a SQL query into a program that dumps that data into a cloud files system (S3, HDFS?), then I will want to convert that data into a format that can be read with DynamoDB.

So I need these things:

1) A transport device, I want to be able to type something like this on the command line:

```
sqlplus ... "SQL Query" | transport --output_path --output_type etc etc
```

2) For the path I need a cloud file system, S3 looks like the obvious choice since I want a turn key solution here.

3) This last part is a nice to have because I can always use a temp directory to hold my raw text and convert it in another step.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the "cloud directory" or "cloud file system" you are referring to is S3? I don't see how it could be anything else in this context, but you are using very vague terms.

Triggering the DynamoDB insert to happen whenever you copy a new file to S3 is pretty simple, just have S3 trigger a Lambda function to process the data and insert into DynamoDB. I'm not clear on how you are going to get the data into S3 though. If you are just running a cron job to periodically query Oracle and dump some data to a file, which you then copy to S3, then that should work.

You need to know that you can't append to a file on S3, you would need to write the entire file each time you push new data to S3. If you are wanting to stream the data somehow then using Kenesis instead of S3 might be a better option.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've edited my OP to be clear in what I need.